# Did I implement this Insertion Sort correctly?

Tags: vb.net, insertion-sort

I've got several Threads with queues of objects that they're processing, while another thread reads and creates these objects from various input. There are certain objects that have to be processed by a specific thread, where as others can be processed by any free thread (thus the reason for not using one queue for all of them), but I still want to keep the loads reasonably balanced. I have an array with all of the ConcurrentQueues that each of the threads use and I'd like to order them based on their count. Since most of the time the queues will be nearly sorted, Insertion Sort would perform well here.

(Edit: For those asking, I'm writing my own because according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.100).aspx "This method uses the QuickSort algorithm," and I want an insertion sort)

I used http://en.literateprograms.org/Insertion_sort_(Visual_Basic_.NET) to give me a hand, but I don't really trust myself. Does this look correct?

```
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While (i < MaxThreads)

            Dim j As Integer = i - 1
            Dim v As Concurrent.BlockingCollection(Of BufferEntry) = ThreadQueues(i)

            While (j > -1)
                If (ThreadQueues(j).Count <= v.Count) Then Exit While
                ThreadQueues(j + i) = ThreadQueues(j)

                j -= 1
            End While

            ThreadQueues(j + 1) = v

            i += 1
        End While
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own Sort?  Don't do that, use Array.Sort()

Comment: @HansPassant Because, according to MSDN, Array.Sort uses QuickSort. I want insertion sort

Comment: @HansPassant Where does it say it uses Introsort, because it definitely says Quicksort on the Array.Sort MSDN page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall it looks pretty good, but I think this line

```
ThreadQueues(j + i) = ThreadQueues(j)
```

should be

```
ThreadQueues(j + 1) = ThreadQueues(j)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for catching that!